# Problems with authentication using passport and google API - InternalOAuthError is occurring

Tags: node.js, passport.js

So, I'm having some problems with google authentication and passport.

I'm using these configs:

- "passport": "^0.2.2"
- "passport-google-oauth2": "^0.1.6"

and also, I have oAuth ID configured in console.developers.google:

- The first config I'm using for localhost server, and works fine
- The second config I'm using a specific server, but is not working. I
  can see the google page, select and signup with my user, but when a
  received the callback method ( *http://[server]:[port]/?code=[...]* ) an error has occurred (*InternalOAuthError*).

Here is the log:

```
InternalOAuthError: Failed to obtain access token
   at Strategy.OAuth2Strategy._createOAuthError ([...]/server/node_modules/passport-google-oauth2/node_modules/passport-oauth2/lib/strategy.js:348:17)
   at [...]/server/node_modules/passport-google-oauth2/node_modules/passport-oauth2/lib/strategy.js:171:43
   at [...]/server/node_modules/passport-google-oauth2/node_modules/passport-oauth2/node_modules/oauth/lib/oauth2.js:177:18
   at ClientRequest.<anonymous> ([...]/server/node_modules/passport-google-oauth2/node_modules/passport-oauth2/node_modules/oauth/lib/oauth2.js:148:5)
   at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:107:17)
   at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:271:9)
   at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:129:20)
   at net.js:459:14
   at process._tickDomainCallback (node.js:381:11)
```

I'd like to know if someone has the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the same problem you were facing, but I got a very similar error message:

```
InternalOAuthError: failed to obtain access token
    at /app/node_modules/passport-oauth/lib/passport-oauth/strategies/oauth2.js:125:38
    at /app/node_modules/oauth/lib/oauth2.js:177:18
    at passBackControl (/app/node_modules/oauth/lib/oauth2.js:123:9)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/oauth/lib/oauth2.js:143:7)
    at emitNone (events.js:85:20)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:179:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:913:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
```

In my case the `Client ID` did not match the `Client secret`, make sure they are matched from the Google Developer's Console:

https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials/oauthclient/